# Show $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]8-\sqrt{\sqrt2+1}\;}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]8+\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}\;} -\sqrt{\sqrt[4]8-\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}\;}}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, nested-radicals, rationality-testing

Days ago, I tried to demonstrate this equality, reducing radicals, multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator, etc. But, I did not reach anything similar to the right side.

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{8}-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\;}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{8}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\;} -\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{8}-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\;}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Can you help?  I lack vision for this problem. You may have fantastic tricks that I have not heard about.

Good 2020!

Comment: Can you give us your expression after conjugating the denominator?

Comment: First, multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt[8]2$ to get $$\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}}$$

Comment: @Don Thousand,thanks for the suggestion

Comment: ,@dskeletov thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 4):

Apply the denest formula $\sqrt{a-\sqrt c}=\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-c}}2}-\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-c}}2} $ to the numerator

$$N=\sqrt{\sqrt[4]8-\sqrt{\sqrt2+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[4]8+\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}}2}-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[4]8-\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}}2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}D$$

where $D$ is the denominator.

---

Alternatively, evaluate

$$D^2 = \left(\sqrt{\sqrt[4]8+\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}}-\sqrt{\sqrt[4]8-\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}}\right)^2$$
$$=\sqrt[4]8+\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}+\sqrt[4]8-\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}-2\sqrt{\sqrt8-(\sqrt2-1)}$$
$$=2\sqrt[4]8-2\sqrt{\sqrt2+1}=2N^2$$

Thus, $\frac ND = \frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: ,thanks, halfway I was close, then I went the other way

Comment: @zeros - no problem; glad it helps

Answer (score 2):

First square both sides and cross multiply to get

$$2\sqrt[4]{8}-2\sqrt{\sqrt 2+1}=2\sqrt[4]{8}-2\sqrt{2\sqrt[4]{4}-\sqrt 2 +1}$$

Notice that  $$\sqrt[4]{4}=\sqrt 2$$ Thus the two sides are equal.

Comment: Mohammad Riazi-Kermani, Thank you for your explanation but I have a doubt, when we speak exclusively of "" demonstrate "", "we should start from the left side and reach the right side" and not work with both sides, because according to understanding a test is less rigorous than a demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{8}-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\;}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{8}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\;} -\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{8}-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\;}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[4]{8}-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}{2\sqrt[4]8-2\sqrt{2\sqrt2-\sqrt2+1}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$